# OxyPlot horizontal scrolling

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

I want to implement chart scrolling.

How can I implemet horizontal scroll bar in OxyPlot? I can not find anything connected to this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no scrollbar in Oxyplot. I needed one for my project and I ended up using a scrollbar from windows forms, manually adjusting it according to zoom level. [image]

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but if possible, can you share how you added and bound the scrollbar to your model?  This would be extremely helpful!!

Answer (score -1):

Oxyplot supports zooming and panning by default.

- '+' = zoom in
- '-' = zoom out
- 'left arrow' = pan left
- 'right arrow' = pan right

You can also use mouse wheel to zoom and right click to pan.

Is there a reason why you need a horizontal scroll bar given that default pan and zoom seems to serve the same purpose.

Comment: Is there a reason? - Yes. There is. When a user sees a scroll bar the user instantly knows how to manipulate this plot. Otherwise one have to... provide a manual or help window with key bindings help? It is so much complicated!